# How to draw contour map?

Tags: python-3.x, contour

I'm beginner for Python. I believe Python will do this task for 3D contour map. 
I have data such as below

```
Y/X (mm),   0,  10, 20, 30, 40
686.6,  -5.02,  -0.417, 0,  100.627,    0
694.08, -5.02,  -4.529, -17.731,    -5.309, -3.535
701.56, 1.869,  -4.529, -17.731,    -5.309, -3.535
709.04, 1.869,  -4.689, -17.667,    -5.704, -3.482
716.52, 4.572,  -4.689, -17.186,    -5.704, -2.51 
724,    4.572,  -4.486, -17.186,    -5.138, -2.51
731.48, 6.323,  -4.486, -16.396,    -5.138, -1.933
738.96, 6.323,  -4.977, -16.396,    -5.319, -1.933
746.44, 7.007,  -4.251, -16.577,    -5.319, -1.688
753.92, 7.007,  -4.251, -16.577,    -5.618, -1.688
761.4,  7.338,  -3.514, -16.78, -5.618, -1.207
768.88, 7.338,  -3.514, -16.78, -4.657, -1.207
776.36, 7.263,  -3.877, -15.99, -4.657, -0.822
```

Any help How to start..

**Update Question**

(1) As you can see the raw data, they has xlabel and ylabel in respectively 1st row, 1st column. 
If I use [numpy.loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html?highlight=numpy.loadtxt#numpy.loadtxt) function, How to split "xs" and "ys" ?

```
data = numpy.loadtxt('131014-data-xy-conv-1.txt')
```

(2) Do you have ay idea to rotate the matrix M x N from ?

(3) linespace has start = -70 and stop = 60, and num= 60, Do you have any idea how to make a step 5 ?

```
contour = subplot.contourf(xs, ys, data, levels=numpy.linspace(-70, 60, 60))
```

Comment: You should really create a new question, because your update has nothing to do with the original one. But the short answer is: use array splicing (it will look like ``xs = data[0,1:]; ys = data[1:,0]; heights = data[1:,1:]``). I cannot give an exact answer, since the data from your question cannot be loaded with ``loadtxt`` in its current form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org), namely its [`contourf`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.contourf) function:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy


xs = numpy.array([0,  10, 20, 30, 40])
ys = numpy.array([686.6, 694.08, 701.56, 709.04, 716.52,
    724, 731.48, 738.96, 746.44, 753.92, 761.4, 768.88, 776.36])

data = numpy.array([
    [-5.02,  -0.417, 0,  100.627,    0],
    [-5.02,  -4.529, -17.731,    -5.309, -3.535],
    [1.869,  -4.529, -17.731,    -5.309, -3.535],
    [1.869,  -4.689, -17.667,    -5.704, -3.482],
    [4.572,  -4.689, -17.186,    -5.704, -2.51],
    [4.572,  -4.486, -17.186,    -5.138, -2.51],
    [6.323,  -4.486, -16.396,    -5.138, -1.933],
    [6.323,  -4.977, -16.396,    -5.319, -1.933],
    [7.007,  -4.251, -16.577,    -5.319, -1.688],
    [7.007,  -4.251, -16.577,    -5.618, -1.688],
    [7.338,  -3.514, -16.78, -5.618, -1.207],
    [7.338,  -3.514, -16.78, -4.657, -1.207],
    [7.263,  -3.877, -15.99, -4.657, -0.822]])

fig = plt.figure()
subplot = fig.add_subplot(111, xlabel='$x$, mm', ylabel='$y$, mm')

contour = subplot.contourf(xs, ys, data, levels=numpy.linspace(-20, 120, 20))
subplot.set_xlim((xs[0], xs[-1]))
subplot.set_ylim((ys[0], ys[-1]))
fig.colorbar(contour)

fig.savefig('t.png')
```

[image: The result]

You can see what's `matplotlib` is capable of [here](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html).

Comment: cool! Thanks. However, I have ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'. I'm using Eclipse Standard/SDK Version: Kepler Release Build id: 20130614-0229.

Comment: Well, same as with any other Python package, you will have to install it. The procedure differs depending on your OS, and may be as easy as ``pip install matplotlib`` if you have all the required libraries (``ghostsrcipt``, ``libpng`` and several else which I cannot recall at the moment). You should look it up, the installation procedure has been described multiple times in many places on the internet.

Comment: As you can see the raw data, they has xlabel and ylabel in respectively 1st row, 1st column. If I use numpy.loadtxt function, How to split "xs" and "ys" ? 
'data = numpy.loadtxt('131014-data-xy-conv-1.txt')'

Do you have ay idea to rotate the matrix M x N from ?